# Which algorithms have been proposed to learn the architecture of a deep neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, deep-learning

Yoshua Benhgio's [Learning Deep Architectures for AI](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/papers/ftml_book.pdf) book mentions that

> we should [...] strive to develop learning algorithms that use the data to determine the depth of the ﬁnal architecture.

Would anyone know of any algorithms proposed thus far to achieve this?

This question is not about successful algorithms - in fact it seems there are none at the moment. The aim of this question is to aggregate every single algorithm that has ever been *proposed* so that anyone interested in the topic doesn't need to spend months finding them.

So far I have come across:

---

- The [tiling algorithm](http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/22/12/019)

  - advantage: adds layers as well as units
  - caveat: only for learning Boolean functions, which aren't too relevant for applied problems.

---

- Genetic algorithms (courtesy of user [vzn](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/7884/vzn)):

  - [Finding Optimal Neural Network Architecture Using Genetic Algorithms](http://www.iidia.com.ar/rgm/articulos/RCSJ-27-15-24.pdf)
  - [Using genetic algorithms to select architecture of a feedforward artificial neural network](http://www.sfu.ca/~rgencay/jarticles/pa-genetic.pdf)
  - advantage: learns continuous functions, ie relevant for applied problems
  - caveat: computationally very expensive

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, the most used algorithm to learn the architecture of a neural network is Cascade Correlation, developed by Scott Fahlman and Christian Lebiere.

[Here](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2937&context=compsci) you can find the description, I also saw a C implementation somewhere before, but couldn't remember where.

Answer (score 3):

There are other popular genetic algorithms like NEAT and EANT both "growing" neural networks. Search for recent papers on them to get a good overview of other approaches (related work).

Another approach than growing is to start with a huge fully connected network and prune connections until the fitness takes a hit. Mitchells book on machine learning gives a good overview.

And of course there are various algorithms employing both growing and pruning. They sometimes involve "fixing" some established part of the networks so that the fixed weights need not be considered for optimization any more.

Answer (score 2):

I've used successfully genetic algorithms to search the optimal configuration for neural networks (units an levels) using my own program (called TSAGANN).

Here there is the  [paper](http://www.godelia.org/blog/view/27312/search-of-optimal-neural-net-structures-using-genetic-algorithms-and-simulated-annealing-verify-with-the-benchmark-proben1) (sorry but is in spanish).

My work was focused on:

- study of structure (units number and hidden leves) of ANN of type feedforward ANN trained with bacpropagation;
- study of Simulated Annealing (SA) (rather ANN).

Results was than SA performs well as ANN for the problems under study and it is less intensive for calculations.

Further work (never done) was the optimization of structure and weights of ANN directly with GA. In this case is not necessary backpropagation because weights are optimized by GA and not by ANN. Traing set is used to calculate only the error for any particular configuration. GA minimizes a variant of the quadratic error. Preliminary study in this sense was very promising (the objective is to avoid training algorithm of ANN, very very slow).

Paper reports results with PROBEN1, a benchmark that cover both, problems of classification and approximation.

"Global optimization" (including weights) seems to be very promising for time series analysis, in order to do forecasting without the use of recurrent ANNs.

Comment: awesome, you should translate your paper in Spanish so that we can all learn from it! how large was your network? (number of layers, number of neurons, number of parameters)

Comment: Sure. Translation requires some time but I will do it. However, tables report structure and parameters of best nets , and a statistical study of results too. This part contains only numerical data and it is clear enough to understand their validity.

Comment: let us know when it's out!

Comment: At the same link to my paper I gave in my response you can find an english version. Translation was done with Google Translator a it's not perfect. Probably you have to use the original in order to follow the discussion and equations numbering.

Comment: The link isn't working anymore. Was it this one? http://polar.lsi.uned.es/revista/index.php/ia/article/view/532

Comment: Yes, it is the paper.